# How to delete dict (JSON object) in a list?

Tags: python

I'm deleting the movie releases which have a different m_y (month_year e.g 12_2018) from my region releases list. I pass its complete movie object in the delete method to remove that object from the list(s), here's my code:

```
def remove_release_object(self, release_object, month_year):
    # Quick fix, to delete this exact item, set ti back
    release_object['m_y'] = month_year
    if release_object['region'] == 1:
        self.releases[month_year]["europe"].remove(release_object)
    if release_object['region'] == 2:
        self.releases[month_year]["north_america"].remove(release_object)
    if release_object['region'] == 3:
        self.releases[month_year]["australia"].remove(release_object)
    if release_object['region'] == 4:
        self.releases[month_year]["new_zealand"].remove(release_object)
    if release_object['region'] == 5:
        self.releases[month_year]["japan"].remove(release_object)
    if release_object['region'] == 8:
        # Worldwide release really only applies to the big region (na, eu, jp, aus, nz)
        self.releases[month_year]["europe"].remove(release_object)
        self.releases[month_year]["north_america"].remove(release_object)
        self.releases[month_year]["australia"].remove(release_object)
        self.releases[month_year]["new_zealand"].remove(release_object)
        self.releases[month_year]["japan"].remove(release_object)
```

After calling remove() it still doesn't work, I even tried to set a quick fix to put the object like it was initially with seeting the old m_y, but still nothing gets removed

Comment: Could you show how the `self.releases` looks like? Maybe something like `del self.releases[month_year]["europe"]` would work? Or do you try to achieve something else?

Comment: I want to remove the object passed in parameter from the list, and it looks like this: {"12_2018":["europe":[{movie_object} ,{...}]]]}

Comment: Got you, is the passed `release_object` really the same as the `movie_object` in the list? My guess is that this doesn't match and therefore python is not able to delete the `movie_object` from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python called `__eq__` when you want to remove one item in one list. This is an example help you understand it.

```
class A(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print('eq was called')
        return True

l = [A()]
print(l)
l.remove(A())
print(l)
```

That means you have to promise release_object is comparable and release_object equal to movie_object.

Another point, dict is comparable and {'a': 1} is equal to another {'a': 1}. That means your release_object not equal to movie_object. You can try:

```
l = [{'a': 1}]
print(l)
l.remove({'a': 1})
print(l)
```

So you should check your code, and check the difference between release_object and movie_object.